# Moore Machines with n states

Tags: finite-automata

I am working on an end of chapter question regarding how many different Moore machines there are with n states. Where n = number of states, m = number of input letters, and q = number of output characters, is it correct that there are n*q^m possible machines? My reasoning is that for each state, each input has the possibility to lead to one of the give output characters.

Comment: When do you count two moore-machines as identical? When they have the same output for every input? Or does the model have to be identical?

Comment: The Moore machines are identical if they have the same output for every input.

Comment: Are you sure? I think, it would be _very_ difficult to solve (if at all) in that case

Comment: The question just says: Based on the table representation for Moore machines how many different machines are there with n states.

Comment: Ok, that means how many different models are there (where two or more can have the same output). That's not as hard.

Answer (score 1):

A Moore machine consists of:

- set of states S (n)
- start state s0
- input alphabet Sigma (m)
- output alphabet A (q)
- transition function (S x Sigma -> S)
- output function (S -> A)

The number of states and input/output-characters is given.

For the **start state** there are *n* possibilities.

For the **transition function**, there are |S| ^ (|S| * |Sigma|) = *n^(n*m)* different variants.

Finally, there are |A| ^ |S| = *q^n* **output functions**

This yields in total *n^(n*m+1) * q^n* different Moore machines.